# Issues filtering based on description

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am having issues filtering out accounts in a `Search-ADAccount` query. The query always returns the 40 days inactive AD accounts that are enabled and have logged in at least once. However a number of accounts being returned are flagged as long-term sickness, maternity leavers or are Helpdesk accounts. In the users' objects the keyword will appear at least once, hence my use of `-notlike` to have the wildcard function. But it still does not work, any ideas are much appreciated!

```
$excludelist = "Sickness", "Maternity", "Helpdesk"
$users = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan (New-TimeSpan -Days 40) -Searchbase "OU=Users,OU=State,DC=Company,DC=Biz" |
         where {($_.enabled -eq $true) -and
                ($_.Description -notlike $excludelist) -and
                ($_.LastLogonDate -notlike $null) } |
         Get-ADUser -Properties mail, manager, LastLogonTimeStamp
```

**UPDATE:** Based off the help in the comments, I have updated the code however the filtering does not apply. Here is the full code;

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Set our non-changing variables for the email
$SMTPServer = "SMTP-Server@company.de"
$From = "Helpdesk <Helpdesk@company.de>"

#Set Testing if needed
$testing = "Enabled" #Set to disabled to go live
$testRecipient = "adam@company.de"

#Set Description Modifiers:
$excludelist = 'Sickness|Maternity|Helpdesk'

#Query AD for all the NCE accounts with no activity for 40 days and are enabled
$users = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan (New-TimeSpan -Days 40) -Searchbase "OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=Company,DC=de" | 
Where-Object {
    $_.Enabled -and
    $_.Description -notmatch $excludelist -and
    $_.LastLogonDate
} | Get-ADUser -Properties mail, manager, LastLogonTimeStamp, description

#Loop through the query results
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    #Convert LastLogonDate to days since last use
    $lastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($User.lastLogonTimeStamp)
    $Daysinactive = ((Get-Date) - $lastLogon).Days

    #Get manager email with passthrough
    $Manager = Get-ADUser $User.Manager -Properties EmailAddress

    #Set dynamic variables and body of email
    $To = $Manager.EmailAddress
    $Subject = "Your employee $($User.Givenname) $($User.Surname) has not been active since $Daysinactive days."
    $Body = 
    "Hello $($Manager.GivenName),<br>
<p>The account of $($User.Givenname) $($User.Surname) has not been active for $Daysinactive days. Please explain in return email.
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>eIPN</td>
<td>email</td>
<td>Inactive Days</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$($User.Givenname) $($User.Surname)</td>
<td>$($User.SamAccountName)</td>        
<td>$($User.mail)</td>
<td>$Daysinactive</td>
<td>$($User.Description)</td>
<td>$excludelist</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>Thanks you.<br>
<p>IT Helpdesk"

    #Testing check before email is sent
    if (($testing) -eq "Enabled") {
        $To = $testRecipient
    } # End Testing

    #Send email
    Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -Priority High
}
```

To test, I have added in the `$($User.Description)` and `$excludelist` into the email table to ensure that the values are being read.

A user that should be filtered is returning a table such as thus:

[image]

So I can see that `user.description` is being read with the excluded word "Helpdesk" in it, but it does not filter.

I have also tried to set the `$exludelist` to simply "Helpdesk" but that does not filter either.

Any help is appreciated. I have tried every method of writing the filtering method I can find online but still no luck!

Comment: Sickness and Maternity is exactly equal, however helpdesk is part of a longer string Helpdesk Operator Account, or a variation of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A condition `<value> -notlike <list>` won't work. The `-notlike` operator (as well as the `-like` operator) can only compare a value to another value with a wildcard pattern. Also, you only want items that have neither of the given strings in the description, so you'd have to define the filter like this:

```
Where-Object {
  $descr = $_.Description
  -not ($excludelist | Where-Object {$descr -like "*$_*"})
}
```

If you want to check whether an attribute doesn't contain any of a given list of strings it's simpler to use a regular expression and the `-notmatch` operator. Also, the properties of the objects returned by `Search-ADAccount` don't include the attribute `description`, so you can't filter on that property before running `Get-ADUser` (which you must instruct to fetch that attribute). Another thing you may want to do is add the parameter `-UsersOnly` to `Search-ADAccount` to prevent it from fetching computer accounts and the like.

Change your code to this:

```
$excludelist = 'Sickness|Maternity|Helpdesk'
$users = Search-ADAccount ... -UsersOnly |
         Where-Object { $_.Enabled -and $_.LastLogonDate } |
         Get-ADUser -Properties mail, manager, LastLogonTimeStamp, Description |
         Where-Object { $_.Description -notmatch $excludelist }
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I have added in your code exactly as you have, however the accounts are still not being filtered. I am at a loss, anything I could check?

Code as it is now:

     `$excludelist = 'Sickness|Maternity|Helpdesk'`

     `$users = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan (New-TimeSpan -Days 40) -Searchbase "OU=Users,OU=State,DC=Company,DC=Biz" | `

`Where-Object {
  $_.Enabled -and
  $_.Description -notmatch $excludelist -and
  $_.LastLogonDate
} | Get-ADUser -Properties mail, manager, LastLogonTimeStamp, description`

Comment: @Adam I don't sit in front of your computer, so please provide evidence. Edit your question and show it there.

Comment: apologies, I am new to StackOverflow and English is not my native tongue. I have updated my question as you advised. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked after the edit. Thank you for your patience and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The `-like` operator(s) doesn't work well with an array as its right hand argument:

```
PS C:\> "a" -notlike "a","b"
True
```

Since `-like` (or any variation, including `-notlike`) expects a string on the right hand, it converts the array to a single string and so your filter effectively becomes:

```
$_.Description -notlike "Sickness Maternity Helpdesk"
```

I doubt this will ever exclude anyone :)

---

You can use the `-contains` operator instead:

```
$excludelist -notcontains $_.Description
```

Or the `-in` operator (PowerShell 3.0 or newer):

```
$_.Description -notin $excludelist
```